# PSExec not working against windows XP (metasploit)

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux, user-enumeration, windows-xp

I am following the book *Penetration Testing: A Hands-On Introduction to Hacking* from Georgia Weidman. In Ch 13, page 296 the psexec from metasploit is used against a *Windows XP Profession SP3 (32-bit)*, but I got the following error:

Exploit failed [no-access]: Rex::Proto::SMB::Exceptions::LoginError Login Failed: The server responded with error: STATUS_LOGON_TYPE_FAILURE (Command=115 WordCount=0)

See above options for my exploit:
[image: ps exec options - exploit/windows/smb/psexec]

I have also set the windows xp machine to behave like part of a domain:
Start --> Run.. --> secpool.msc --> Security Settings --> Local Policies --> Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts --> Classic - Local Users authenticate as themselves.

[image: xp security seetings to be part of domain]

and set it up the SMBDomain to WORKGROUP. When using **enum4linux**, my user (shariff) is not enumerated, but this is the one that I use to login (I also have the hash for it but again not working). Does this suggest that there is some setting that is not allowing me to connect??
[image: enum4linux -U 1]
[image: enum4linux -U 2]

This is driving me crazy.. any suggestions or ideas to fix this? username and password is correct, but still login failure error. Is there anything that I am missing?? *How I can test smb to see if I can login with my user??*

Comment: please do not use screenshots for console output - copy/paste with the `code ` formatting means we can read it

Comment: @schroeder took note of it for next posts, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the SMBDomain to a single dot "." or the system name rather than WORKGROUP and see what happens.

Comment: not sure why, but now it works! I restored some snapshot, and let SMBDomain to be a . and it worked. So, can you explain to me why it was not working with WORKGROUP? (From enum4linux the domain name is WORKGROUP). Thanks!